# SilverLight 5 and VS2019 - missing assembly reference?

Tags: c#, silverlight-5.0

I have a SilverLight app and I'm trying to make it work with VS2019 and .NET 4.7.2, SilverLight - 5.0

I get following error while compiling:

```
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'TabItem' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows.Controls' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

How to fix this?

I tried to add reference to `System.Windows.Controls` from framework, but it doesn't exist, in order to support SilverLight in VS2019 i use this extension:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RamiAbughazaleh.SilverlightProjectSystem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the Silverlight Toolkit

[Silverlight 5 Toolkit December 2011.1](https://github.com/microsoftarchive/SilverlightToolkit/releases/download/5/Silverlight_5_Toolkit_December_2011.1.msi)

[Silverlight Toolkit on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoftarchive/SilverlightToolkit)

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight stopped being officially supported in VS2017, you should use VS2015 instead.

[This is detailed in the VS2017 compatibility notes here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/vs2017-compatibility-vs#silverlight)

If you are using an plugin to make this work in 2019 I would recommend contacting the plugin owner for assistance.

Comment: I use this VS Extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RamiAbughazaleh.SilverlightProjectSystem to load SilverLight in VS2019